# wcin gets wrong character input?

Tags: c++, unicode, console-application

The following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::wcin;
using std::wcout;
using std::locale;


int main()
{
    locale::global(locale("Portuguese_Brazil"));

    wcout << "wcin Test using \"ção\": "; // shows that wcout works properly
    wchar_t wcinTest[] = L"";
    wcin >> wcinTest;
    wcout << wcinTest << " should be \"ção\".";

    return 0;
}
```

Results in:

```
wcin Test using "ção": ção
╬Æo should be "ção".
```

The ╬ character is U+2021 or 8225, and the ç is U+00E7 or 231.

I changed mult-bytes option, set and not set UNICODE in project properties. Nothing worked.

I already set the console font into Consolas, a true type font capable of displaying the ç character correctly.

I'd like this as simple and reproducible possible to use as a standard practice for future UNICODE console applications.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This finally worked:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::string;




int main()
{
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1252);
    SetConsoleCP(1252);

    cout << "wcin Test using \"ção\": "; // shows that wcout works properly
    string wcinTest;
    cin >> wcinTest;
    cout << wcinTest << " should be \"ção\".";

    return 0;
}
```

I'm too newbie to understand why I need both **SetConsoleOutputCP** and **SetConsoleCP**. I though maybe just SetConsoleCP would fix everything, but no, I need both: **SetConsoleOutputCP** fixed ***cout***; and **SetConsoleCP** fixed ***cin***.

Thanks anyway @StoryTeller

Comment: I agree, but it solved my specific issue, even if I had to drop the utf8 for that. Current C++ handles this much better and the console just needs to use unicode font.

Answer (score 4):

`wcinTest` is a `wchar_t` buffer of length 1;

You overflow it when you read into it. Use a [`std::wstring`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) insead.

Comment: Still, no good. Same result with wstring.
This is what I tried:
' #include <iostream>'
 #include <string>

 using std::wcin;
 using std::wcout;
 using std::wstring;
 using std::locale;
 //using namespace std;


 int main()
 {
  locale::global(locale("Portuguese_Brazil"));

  wcout << "wcin Test using \"ção\": ";
  wstring wcinTest;
  wcin >> wcinTest;
  wcout << wcinTest << " should be \"ção\".";

  return 0;
 }`

Comment: I think I'm on to something.
I just realized that I broke my cin while fixing my cout output with locale("Portuguese_Brazil"). I removed that and use #include <Windows.h> and everything works!